# AWS SDK v2: While copying files on S3: TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendToUserAgent' of undefined

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I'm calling the `copyObject` method of aws-sdk `v2` 's S3 class:

```js
const s3 = new AWS.S3({...s3Config});
// attempt 1
let copyObject = {
    Bucket: 'my-bucket-name',
    CopySource: `s3://my-bucket-name/my/file/path`,
    Key: `/my/destination/path`,
}

await s3.copyObject(copyObj);

// attempt 2
copyObject = {
    Bucket: 'my-bucket-name',
    CopySource: `my-bucket-name/my/file/path`,
    Key: `/my/destination/path`,
}

await s3.copyObject(copyObj);
```

Both fail with the same error:

```
Cannot read property 'appendToUserAgent' of undefined
```

Pointing to `at promise (/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:780:22)`. Am I missing something here? I referred to this documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at Dzmitry Luhauskoi's answer, I realized that I was using the `.promise` in a for loop among other things and using `Promise.all()`. When I removed it from the array of promises and ran in its own separate promise, it ran successfully. I don't know why the AWS SDK's promise method is not compatible with most other promise related features of nodejs...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help someone, I've got this error when tried to use `promisify()` on a `send()` function. It seems like function loses context or something. I promisified it manually with `return new Promise(resolve => {})...` and everything started to work as expected.